# Validation rule to prevent more than a certain number of one character in a text field

Tags: validation-rule, regular-expressions

Is it possible to include in a validation rule for a text field to only allow X amount of commas? I am trying to limit the amount of emails that are currently seperated by a comma.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. You will need to use a regular expression to check this. You can use the [REGEX](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_regex.htm&type=5) function in Salesforce.

If your limit on commas is 10, your regular expression will be:

```
^[^,\r\n]*(?:,[^,\r\n]*){11,}$
```

For context, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464461/regular-expression-to-match-text-that-contains-n-or-more-of-specified-character) on Stack Overflow.

Your formula would be:

```
REGEX(Your_Field__c, "^[^,\r\n]*(?:,[^,\r\n]*){11,}$")
```

To change the number of commas allowed, adjust the 11 to be one more than the maximum number of commas.

Comment: Sorry for the late response but thank you for the help!!

Comment: If it helped can you mark it as best answer please?